# validation for dynamically added fields

Tags: angularjs

i have a form in that i provide an option to add fileds dynamically, for that i used ng-repeat, my promblem is for that added field form validation is not working. Here is my working code.

```
<fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices"  ng-init="count=0">
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">Designation </label>
                 <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" name="desg_{{$index}}" class="form-control" ng-model="user2.choices[choice.id]" placeholder="Your Job Title" required/>
                <span ng-messages="employeeform['desg_' + $index].$error"  ng-show="employeeform['desg_' + $index].$touched || employeeform.$submitted">
                    <span ng-message = "required"  class="errorcol">select day</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
              </div>
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">Company </label>
                 <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company_{{$index}}" ng-focus="usercompany_msg=true" ng-model="user2.choices[choice.id_f]" placeholder="where your are currently working"/>
                    <p ng-show="errorDesg">{{errorDesg}}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
</fieldset>`
```

` -
and my controller code is

```
$scope.addfields = function(){
console.log($scope.choices.length);
if($scope.choices.length<3){
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
    var item = {};
    item.id = "company" + newItemNo;
    item.id_f = "designation" + newItemNo;
    item.id_s = "sallac" + newItemNo;
    item.id_t = "saltho" + newItemNo;
    $scope.choices.push(item);
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.choices));
}
};
```

the error i am getting is

[image: errorimage]

Comment: Could you describe the error? is there an error in the debug console of your browser?

Comment: The error you gives may be telling that you have kinda syntax error around `ng-messages="employeeform['desg_' + $index].$error"`. But i have no idea why. It looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

it is a parser error. you have wrong expression inside one of angular directive. try to comment part of your code/ one by one to localize parse error. why do you have ng-init="count=0" inside ng-repeat?